# Return Company Name, undefined Phone Number and Label Group from Google ContactsApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

I'm new to Google Scripts and I've found very helpful information from this forum (Thank you!!). I am trying to create the script to export Google Contacts App into a Sheet. I am able to successfully get the Full Name and Email from the below script, but it is only returning "Company Field", "Phone Field" and "Contact Group". I have tried several variations of the code to try to return the actual name of the Company, Phone Number and Groups (if populated), but it can only return those header values. Any help on this would be amazing!

Here's my code:

```
    function getName() { 
     var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), output = [];  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Create a header record 
var header = [["Full Name", "Company", "Email", "Phone Number", "Tags"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
range.setValues(header);

for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {

//Get Full Name
var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();    
if(fullname) {
  output.push([fullname])
 } 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, output.length, 1).setValues(output);

// Gets Company Name Address

var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), output = [];  
for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
var company = contacts[i].getCompanies();    
if(company) {
  output.push([company]);
} 
 }    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 2, output.length, 1).setValues(output);

// Gets Email Address
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), output = [];  
for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
var email = contacts[i].getEmailAddresses();    
if(email) {
  output.push([email]);
} 
}    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 3, output.length, 1).setValues(output);

 // Gets Phone Number
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), output = [];  
for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
var phone = contacts[i].getPhones();    
if(phone) {
  output.push([phone]);
} 
 }
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 4, output.length, 1).setValues(output);


// Gets Tags
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts(), output = [];  
for(var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
var tags = contacts[i].getContactGroups();    
if(tags) {
  output.push([tags]);
} 
   }  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 5, output.length, 1).setValues(output);

}
```

Comment: I have provided an answer below. Kindly check if that works out on you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods `getCompanies`, `getPhones`, `getContactGroups` return an array of objects. You need to access their values each per element.

#### Code:

```
function getName() {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Create a header record 
  var header = [["Full Name", "Company", "Email", "Phone Number", "Tags"]]
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 5).setValues(header);
  // Delimiter is set into next line within cell
  // Change into comma if you want it delimited by comma
  var delimiter = String.fromCharCode(10);

  for (var i = 0, iLen = contacts.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    // Get last row every loop
    var row = sheet.getLastRow();
    
    var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName();
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 1, 1, 1).setValue(fullname);

    var company = contacts[i].getCompanies(), companies = [];
    for (var j in company)
      if (company[j].getCompanyName())
        companies.push([company[j].getCompanyName()]);  
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 2, 1, 1).setValue(companies.join(delimiter));

    var email = contacts[i].getEmails(), emails = [];
    for (var j in email)
      if (email[j].getAddress()) 
        emails.push([email[j].getAddress()]);
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3, 1, 1).setValue(emails.join(delimiter));

    var phone = contacts[i].getPhones(), phones = [];
    for (var j in phone)
      if (phone[j].getPhoneNumber())
        phones.push([phone[j].getPhoneNumber()]);
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 4, 1, 1).setValue(phones.join(delimiter));

    var tags = contacts[i].getContactGroups(), groups = [];
    for (var j in tags)
      // Default tag in my contacts seems to be "System Group: My Contacts", I did not include them
      if (tags[j].getGroupName() && tags[j].getGroupName() != "System Group: My Contacts") 
        groups.push([tags[j].getGroupName()]);
    sheet.getRange(row + 1, 5, 1, 1).setValue(groups.join(delimiter));
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you NaziA! I am noticing with this change though that the Company is not coming out for every record. It is only populating the sheet with the first Contact in the list. I have some Contacts that are part of multiple groups. Is there a way to extract all of the groups they are part of, and not just the first one?

Comment: Hi @LindsayConnolly, that should not be the case, it should loop into all data. I have updated my answer. kindly see if that works with you. Basically, what I did was change how i show the data. it doesn't just append the data on column, it will append on the last row instead for the new data. and you should see all data under the full name

Comment: Hi @NaziA. Thank you so much! This is working really nicely now. I am seeing it append the different rows for each of the tags. I've tried to actually have it append into Columns instead of Rows, but I couldn't figure that part out. Ultimately, I would have 1 row per Full Name and each Group Name would be populated in a column.

Comment: Hi @LindsayConnolly, I have joined all of them and shown in a single cell. Can you check if that's what you are expecting to see?

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for showing me this code and helping me though it! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @LindsayConnolly, if we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: All set! I am new here! Thanks for explaining the process and for all of your help!